# Bubble sort collection and ignore case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using an bubble sort to sort my list of strings. But if one of my list is an lowercase letter at the beginning of the string, it puts it at the bottom of the list even though the letter may be in the middle. Any help to get the expect output? See below:

```
List output:               expect output:

A                          A
B                          B
C                          C
K                          e
L                          K
e                          L
```

bubble sort code:

```
Public Function SortCollection(colInput As Collection) As Collection
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim iCounter2 As Integer
Dim temp As Variant
 
Set SortCollection = New Collection
For iCounter = 1 To colInput.Count - 1
    For iCounter2 = iCounter + 1 To colInput.Count
        If colInput(iCounter) > colInput(iCounter2) Then
           temp = colInput(iCounter2)
           colInput.Remove iCounter2
           colInput.Add temp, temp, iCounter
        End If
    Next iCounter2
Next iCounter
Set SortCollection = colInput
End Function
```

Comment: `If Ucase(colInput(iCounter)) > UCase(colInput(iCounter2)) Then`

Comment: wow, thank you so much!